# Permission Handling in Inter-Service Calls. (Micro Services)

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, permissions, microservices

I've been assigned with a task to find out the best practices to handle the inter-service communication authorization, I've been going through a lot of internet articles but unfortunately no luck so far.

Use Case - The requirement is to disable permission checks(authorization) if it is an inter-service call and if it is a client call it should work as it is (i.e permission checks enabled).

Desperately waiting for the Hand Of GOD to help me out with this.

Thanks and Regards,
C.

Comment: Possible answer depends on what kind of authorization is used in your projects

Comment: Ola Andrew, thankyou for responding, one way to go around this, what we figured out is to create a standalone permission for this, like 'Interservice Permission' and to do a check based on that, but still I wanted to know if there could be any other better ways around this. No problemo, thankyou once again.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually working on something very similar to your use case where I have API calls from the main app client to my front facing services, I have my backoffice clients APIs for configuration & live operation management, and I have my internal microservices ecosystem communicating with one another.

Best way I can recommend is to have a dedicated place to issue tokens (JWT tokens would be recommended). You can build into your tokens a permission / roles check mechanism. Then you will be able to easily propagate these tokens across your microservices ecosystem and each service can validate the token & roles inside of it to allow access.

I don't like the idea of a general purpose inter-service permission since you essentially say that you either have an access or not (doesn't matter who the user is and what level of access he has), where in real life you might have cases where you have restricted access to some of the APIs or to some of the information on a specific API even in your downstream services.

Comment: Thankyou Lior, for your insightful suggestion. Much appreciated!!